# Are escaped newlines part of POSIX make?

Tags: c, makefile, posix

The [POSIX make](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/make.html) standard page has this to say about escaped newlines (emphasis mine):

> The treatment of escaped s throughout the makefile is **historical practice**. For example, the inference rule:
>
> ```
> .c.o\
> :
> ```
>
> works, and the macro:
>
> ```
> f=  bar baz\
>    biz
> a:
>    echo ==$f==
> ```
>
> echoes `"==bar baz biz=="`.

What does "historical practice" mean?

Can I use escaped newlines in a strictly conforming POSIX makefile or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX standard says this about escaped newlines (this is in the actual standard text not in the informative sections or rational):

> When an escaped <*newline*> (one preceded by a <*backslash*>) is found
>   anywhere in the makefile except in a command line, an include line, or
>   a line immediately preceding an include line, it shall be replaced,
>   along with any leading white space on the following line, with a
>   single <*space*>. When an escaped <*newline*> is found in a command line
>   in a makefile, the command line shall contain the <*backslash*>, the
>   <*newline*>, and the next line, except that the first character of the
>   next line shall not be included if it is a <*tab*>. When an escaped
>   <*newline*> is found in an include line or in a line immediately
>   preceding an include line, the behavior is unspecified.

That is the POSIX mandated behavior you an rely on with respect to escaped newlines.